# Using maven properties in JavaDoc

Tags: java, maven, javadoc

Is it possible to expand the maven properties' scope on javadocs using Maven Javadoc Plugin? E.g.

```
/**
 * My Awesome Class
 * @version ${project.version}
**/
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you try like this. This is two step process:
First is to load the pom property into static field
Second to use the static field to set the javadoc property

Create a `app.properties` in `src/main/resources` with content like this

```
application.version=${project.version}
```

then enable maven filtering like this

```
<build>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
        </resource>
    </resources>
```

In application code just read properties file

```
public class MVNLinksHolder{

public static String version = "";

public MVNLinksHolder(){
    ClassPathResource resource = new ClassPathResource( "app.properties" );
    Properties p = new Properties();
    InputStream inputStream = null;
    try {
        inputStream = resource.getInputStream();
        p.load( inputStream );
        version = p.getProperty("application.version");
    }
    catch ( IOException e ) {
        LOGGER.error( e.getMessage(), e );
    }
    finally {
        Closeables.closeQuietly( inputStream );
    }
}
}
```

Then use it to set the version

```
/**
 * My Awesome Class
 * @version = {@value MVNLinksHolder#version}
**/
```

Comment: Is there no easier way to do this in 2018?

Answer (score 0):

> show
>   String 
>   Specifies the access level for classes and members to
>   show in the Javadocs. Possible values are: public (shows only public
>   classes and members) protected (shows only public and protected
>   classes and members) package (shows all classes and members not marked
>   private) private (shows all classes and members)
>
> Default value is: protected. User property is: show.

https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-javadoc-plugin/javadoc-mojo.html

Try putting show to public