# Update variable in source files on maven release

Tags: java, maven, version, maven-release-plugin

Is the maven-release-plugin able to update a variable to actual release version in a *source file*?

As an example, if I have the following class in the source tree:

```
/**
 * Does actually nothing
 * 
 * @since ${project.version}
 */
public class NewClass {
  ...
}
```

the maven release plugin could replace the variable `${project.version}` with the actual version of the generated release.

Comment: If you really need this which I have my doubts about ...see here: https://www.mojohaus.org/templating-maven-plugin/

Answer (score 0):

Getting the version in the source itself requires an additional plugin and can be a bit tricky (see [Generate a Version.java file in Maven](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2469922/generate-a-version-java-file-in-maven)). It may be better to write to the version to a text/config file like in the question [Using maven to output the version number to a text file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3532135/using-maven-to-output-the-version-number-to-a-text-file) and reference that file from the javadoc like in [Javadoc link to src/main/resource or src/test/resource file using relative path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43772805/javadoc-link-to-src-main-resource-or-src-test-resource-file-using-relative-path?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Or since your aim is to use a maven property (version) in javadoc, you could follow the suggestion in [Using maven properties in JavaDoc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31604144/using-maven-properties-in-javadoc), which is to put the version in a config file with maven filtering and read that into a java class that can then be referenced directly in the javadoc